# Flutter bloc weird behavior when listening to same state from 2 different screens

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, bloc, flutter-bloc

**Context:**

So i have a feature that can be executed from two different screens in the app(Screen A & Screen B). That feature is basically a Cubit function that will emit a specific state which both screens are listening to. the BLoC listener then will show a message indicating that the operation was successful.

**Code Samples:**

Screen A:

```
class ScreenA extends StatelessWidget {
  const ScreenA({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocListener<MyCubit, MyState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        if (state == OperationSuccess()) {
          print('Screen A');
        }
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
            child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              child: const Text('Execute Feature'),
              onPressed: () async {
                print('Feature Called From Screen A');
                await context.read<MyCubit>().showMessage();
              },
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              child: const Text('Navigate to ScreenB'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => const ScreenB(),
                    ));
              },
            ),
          ],
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Screen B:

```
import 'package:bloc_listner/cubit/my_cubit.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

class ScreenB extends StatelessWidget {
  const ScreenB({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocListener<MyCubit, MyState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        if (state == OperationSuccess()) {
          print('Screen B');
        }
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              child: const Text('Execute Feature'),
              onPressed: () async{
                print('Feature Called From Screen B');
               await context.read<MyCubit>().showMessage();
              },
            ),
           
          ],
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Cubit:

```
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

part 'my_state.dart';

class MyCubit extends Cubit<MyState> {
  MyCubit() : super(MyInitial());
  
  Future<void> showMessage() async {
    try {
      emit(OperationLoading());
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
      print('Feature Executed');
      emit(OperationSuccess());
    } catch (e) {
      emit(OperationError());
    }
  }
}
```

**Live Example**

[GIF showing app behavior & output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrRJA.gif)

**Output**

[Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgohG.png)

**Expected Behavior**

```
// -Feature Called From Screen A
// -Feature Executed
// -Screen A
// -Feature Called From Screen B
// -Feature Executed
// -Screen B
```

Some Workarounds i though of are:
1-using PushReplacement instead of push to remove the screen A from navigation stack

2-Pairing state checks with a condition indicating if the feature got executed from the current screen something like

```
  if (state == OperationSuccess() && ModalRoute.of(context).isCurrent) {
          print('Screen A');
        }
```

3-using separate cubit/Bloc for every screen however this seems like an overkill since it's a single feature but executed from two different screens

so i wanna know if am i missing something here or if there is better practices to follow

any Help is much appreciated ,Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

This is working as expected. You get notified for every widget which is in navigation stack when the state changes. In case you don't want to listen to the react to the state in screen change, there are couple of ways.

You can use following method

```dart
class ScreenA extends StatefulWidget {
  const ScreenA({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ScreenA> createState() => _ScreenAState();
}

class _ScreenAState extends State<ScreenA> {

  bool _isPushedInsideStack = false; 

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocListener<MyCubit, MyState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        if (!_isPushedInsideStack && state == OperationSuccess()) {
          print('Screen A');
        }
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
            child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              child: const Text('Execute Feature'),
              onPressed: () async {
                print('Feature Called From Screen A');
                await context.read<MyCubit>().showMessage();
              },
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              child: const Text('Navigate to ScreenB'),
              onPressed: () async {
                setState(() {
                 _isPushedInsideStack = true;
                });
                await Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => const ScreenB(),
                    ));
                setState(() {
                 _isPushedInsideStack = false;
                });
              },
            ),
          ],
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks ,buy i'm wondering if there is more apropriate way as i'm already aware of this along of couple other solutions that i put at  the end of the post